# Python server pages, tables and lists

Tags: python, python-server-pages

I am using MySQL and python server pages to show the data in a database. In the db I have selected this data: a list `x =[1, 61, 121, 181, 241, 301]` and a list of lists `z = (['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['g','h'],['i','j'],['k','l'])` and I would like to put these in a table to look like:

```
001   a b
061   c d
121   e f
181   g h
241   i j
301   k l
```

Am I right in thinking that I would have to use two 'for loops' to do this? Here is what I am using:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
z=[]
for row in rows:
    z.append(dict[row[1]]) 
x=[]
for i in range(1, len(rows),60):
    x.append(i)
for i in range(0,len(z), 60):
    req.write("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" %(str(x[i:i+60]), str(z[i:i+60])))
```

And this is what I'm outputting:

```
[1, 61, 121, 181, 241, 301]      a b
                                 c d
                                 e f
                                 g h
                                 i j
                                 k l
```

Any help would be massively appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
for index, (a, b) in zip(x, z):
    print(index, a, b)         # format as appropriate
```

Also, your creation of `z` list might be improved upon:

```
z = [dic[row[1]] for row in rows]         # calling variable dict shadows built-in
```

`x` can either be created as `range(1, len(rows), 60)`

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the "step by 60" twice on `x` -- you're building `x` to have exactly the list you see, already stepped by 60 at a time, and then getting its first 60 items (it doesn't have that many, so you're getting *all* items in fact) with the `str(x[i:i+60])` in the second loop.

Change the second loop to, e.g.:

```
for i in range(0,len(z), 60):
    req.write("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" %(x[i//60], z[i:i+60]))
```

I've also eliminated the redundant `str` calls since the `%s` formatting already does that internally.

Comment: what does this slicing of `z` even mean?

Comment: @SilentGhost, not sure, since of course I can't tell what's coming off the cursor!, but looking at the sample output that part seems to work, so I left it alone;-).

Answer (score 0):

```
#Following code will work in Python 3.x

x =[1, 61, 121, 181, 241, 301]
z = (['a','b'],['c','d'],['e','f'],['g','h'],['i','j'],['k','l'])

for i in zip(x, z):
    print("{0:03} {1} {2}".format(i[0], i[1][0], i[1][1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use iterators instead of arrays + indekses. Foe example use `xrange` instead of `range` etc. It might be beneficial (I don't know MySQL capabilities) to use 2 cursors instead of caching everything in table.
2. There is `zip` function which takes two iteratable - like two arrays.

Example code:

```
for (xe, ze) in zip (x, z):
    req.write("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>" % (xe, ' '.join(ze))
```